# Delete form wont submit

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Im getting this error when im trying to submit my form
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined"
My js file

```
function validateForm() {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit
    var form = document.forms["myForm"]; // storing the form
    swal({
           title: "Are you sure?",
           text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this.",
           icon: "warning",
           buttons: true,
           dangerMode: true,
         })
        .then((willDelete) => {
             if (willDelete) {
                   form.submit();
             }
      });
}
```

how i call the function

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm " onclick="validateForm()">Delete</button>
```

its my first time posting something and am fairly new at coding, it somehow broke and i dont know what im doing

Edit:: how do i point it to this form or any other form if i choose to do so

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.users.destroy', $user->id)}}" method="POST" class="float-left">
 @csrf
{{method_field('DELETE')}}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm " onclick="validateForm()">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: check whether `form` actually is pointing to your form. If not, check whether `myForm` is actually the `name` of your form.

Comment: Your error means that `document.forms["myForm"];` is returning `undefined`. Double-check that you have a form with the id/name of "myForm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an attribute id on your tag form, and the you can have your form with

```
document.getElementById("demo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it thanks for the help Nick, it was missing an id